# Adding data labels with series name to bubble chart

Tags: excel, vba, bubble-chart

I have a macro which adds the data labels in a bubble chart. This code provides the value of the Y axis.

I would like to show the SeriesName instead.

```
Sub AddDataLabels()

Dim bubbleChart As ChartObject
Dim mySrs As Series
Dim myPts As Points

With ActiveSheet
    For Each bubbleChart In .ChartObjects
        For Each mySrs In bubbleChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
            Set myPts = mySrs.Points
            myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue
        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

I tried changing

```
myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue
```

Into:

```
myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowSeriesName
```

It gives me

> 'Invalid procedure call or argument'

How can I change the code to display the SeriesName instead of the Y axis value?

Screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `With` statement in my code below inside your code, and adjust the parameters inside according to your needs.

In the code below the chart `Daralabels` will show the `SeriesName` , but not the Category or Values.

```
Sub AddDataLabels()

Dim bubbleChart As ChartObject
Dim mySrs As Series
Dim myPts As Points

With ActiveSheet
    For Each bubbleChart In .ChartObjects
        For Each mySrs In bubbleChart.Chart.SeriesCollection
            Set myPts = mySrs.Points

            myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels

            With myPts(myPts.Count).DataLabel
                .ShowSeriesName = True
                .ShowCategoryName = False
                .ShowValue = False
                ' optional parameters
                .Orientation = 0
                .Font.Size = 10
                .Font.Bold = True
            End With

        Next
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @RobinEdsmyr your'e welcome, please mark as "answer" (by marking a little **V** next to my post)

Comment: Done! Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

`bubbleChart.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowLabel`

Comment: Unfortunately not. Removing 'myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue' and adding 'bubbleChart.ApplyDataLabels xlDataLabelsShowLabel' it gives an error. However, changing 'myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlShowValue' to 'myPts(myPts.Count).ApplyDataLabels Type:=xlDataLabelsShowLabel', that gives me the value of the x axis instead of the Y axis previously. But not the series name.

Comment: Strange. It Worked for me with my test bubble-chart. might look into it later. Another point: I recon `myPts(myPts.Count).` would result in an error, since the index of `myPts` starts at 0, and you try to access the single item with the index `myPts.Count` (counting obviously starts at 1)